# netbeans plugin? re-writing url

Tags: url-rewriting, netbeans-plugins

At the moment my netbean project running in glassfish server is showing  `http://localhost:8080/projectname/index.html`

I need this changed to  `http://localhost:8080/homepage`

How do I change this url in the title bar.

Or is the only way to make a .htaccess file which needs to be encrypted by placing .htpasswd in WEB-INF etc.  Or maybe there is a plugin.

Let me know, thanks in advance

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Ive solved this problem by using in HTML5 `history.pushstate(null, "title", new url")`
This only renamed index.html index-1 etc.  So in netbeans if you right click on the project --> go to properties --> and go to RUN... you can change the context path and delete the project folder so you get `http://localhost:8080/homepage` not `http://localhost:8080/project/homepage.`

To follow from this I need some further advice which google is not providing.  I want to redirect to an anchor tag in the page such as `href=" /index6.html#content"`.  However using history.pushstate() means the anchor tag is ignored and will always direct the page to the pushstate values.  Anyway around this?

best regards

David